# Google Apps script: Spreadsheet to Chart to Image

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a function to take spreadsheet data, bring it to GAS, and then send it out to a webhook so I can use Zapier to build an image/pdf/etc. I used others samples and help on Google to figure out how to get the range, bring it over, etc and that's here:

```
      const range = "Prior!H20:K23";
  const [header, ...values] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(range)
    .getDisplayValues();
  
  const table = Charts.newDataTable();
    header.forEach((e) => table.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, e));
    values.forEach((e) => table.addRow(e));
  const blob = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataTable(table.build())
    .setDimensions(500, 150)
    .setOption("alternatingRowStyle", false)
    .build()
    .getBlob();
```

I then send the blob out, etc. The problem is that I'm losing all of the formatting from the spreadsheet, and since what I really want to do is almost just take a screenshot of the range in question, it's a problem. Specifically I'm losing text attributes, coloring, and the merging of cells.

Any ideas of how to do this, or, where in here I could modify/bring over the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no quick way to get a spreadsheet range with formatting through the SpreadsheetApp API.

See Tanaike's [RichTextApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#richtexttohtmlforspreadsheet) for one pretty simple method of getting formatted *text* content in a range of cells. The library that uses a temporary document to get the formatting.

To get a chart, complete with formatting, try `.build().getAs('image/png')` or `'image/svg'` instead of `.build().getBlob()`. See [Charts reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts).

Alternatively, use [Sheet.newChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newchart) to get an `EmbeddedTableChartBuilder` instead of a `TableChartBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Is it your thought that instead of getting as a blob, and getting as an image/png, it'll keep the formatting? Because that's the trouble. I create an imagine fine, but it loses all the formatting the spreadsheet has. I tried to get as a png, it just looks identical.

Comment: The `.getAs()` in your code does not get a spreadsheet range — it gets the table chart you just built. You can obviously format the chart as you wish and then get it as .svg or .png, but that will not get the formatting of the spreadsheet range. Will edit the answer with a workaround.

Comment: just for anyone who comes to read this, i ended up having to build it as html to keep/get the formatting, then convert the html to an image, using another api.

Answer (score 0):

#### You will need to extract formatting info from the sheet and feed it into the table builder

(*Disclaimer, even by doing this you won't be able to do it with Apps Script, see below*)

Especially if you use

```
.getDisplayValues();
```

Which will only get the values *displayed* from the sheet, *no formatting information* is taken from the sheet with this method.

You can use:

```
.getRichTextValues()
```

Though unfortunately a [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value), is not recognized by the chart builder.

So the best thing is to break it up into a few steps, the first of which is using:

```
value.getTextStyle()
```

Which will then return a `TextStyle` object that has a few methods:

- `getFontFamily()`
- `getFontSize()`
- `getForegroundColor()`
- `getForegroundColorObject()`
- `isBold()`
- `isItalic()`
- `isStrikethrough()`
- `isUnderline()`

So now you can store the various formats you need to apply to your table.

#### However, the Apps Script Charts Service does not support this styling!

It seems that the Apps Script Chart Service does not support this type of styling. So maybe your only option is to open an HTML UI element via the [UI service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service), or a [Web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and then use the Google Charts service in the way demonstrated by the quickstart https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.

You would need the [`setCell` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#data-format).
This involves translating your styling to CSS, for example:

```js
dataTable.setCell(22, 2, 15, 'Fifteen', {style: 'font-style:bold; font-size:22px;'});
// https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setCell
```

#### File a feature request

You can always file a feature request for that by filling out this template:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905

In the meantime though, you are probably best to get to grips with the JS library as it will always tend to be more complete than the Apps Script service that wraps it.

That, or build an HTML table without using Google Charts, then you could potentially use the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) to pass it around in that format.

#### References

- [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)
- [DataTableBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table-builder)
- [TableChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/table-chart-builder)
- [UI service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service)
- [Web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)
- [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)